# Replacing the symbol "-" in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm working on project where I need to replace a string `– Greek City Times` with an empty string. I'm trying to do it like this.

```
master.DF.new$Title <- enc2utf8(trim(gsub("– Greek City Times", "", master.DF.new$Title)))
```

But the symbol `-` doesn't seem to be picked up.

Comment: `–` and `-` are not the same

Comment: i think that's the problem. but can you please tell how to solve it. because i think its just the same symbol on the keyboard.

Comment: Why not just copy and paste it?

Comment: even if i copy and paste it is not recognising

Comment: What if you use a fixed `gsub`? `gsub("–", "", x, fixed=TRUE)`? There is no sense activating a regex engine. Also, no need to use an additional library. If you need to use it as part of a regex, I can suggest `gsub("*UCP)–", "", x, perl=TRUE)`. Is it on Linux or Windows?

Comment: wow.... that works... thanks a lot for that.... can u please give me a bit more detailing on what was the problem and how does that line helps  @– hwnd

Comment: @Raj, doesn't `gsub("– Greek City Times", "", x, fixed=TRUE)` work? `\p{Pd}` removes *any* Unicode dash, while you need to replace your specific one.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  .... gsub("– Greek City Times", "", x, fixed=TRUE)..this doesn't work... but... gsub('\\p{Pd} Greek City Times', '', master.DF.new$Title, perl=TRUE).... this worked for me.

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: windows.........

Comment: Then you may use `gsub("(*UCP)– Greek City Times", "", x, perl=TRUE)`. The `(*UCP)` PCRE verb will handle the Unicode chars in the pattern correctly.

Comment: I wonder where you got `trim` from, it should be `trimws`. Also, my suggestion works in both Windows and Linux [the same way](http://ideone.com/OjAOTe). Else, `–` is not `–` in your data.

Comment: @Raj, do you want me to post an answer? You are not accepting any, do you mean you want to accept my answer?

Comment: gsub("*UCP)–", "", x, perl=TRUE)........ this was the solution ..... the character that I was not able to capture was the unicode character.... thanks a lot  for all your efforts

Answer (score 1):

You should put single brackets around the dash but within the quotes.
See:

```
gsub(pattern = "[-]", replacement = "", x = "-Greek City Times")
#[1] "Greek City Times"
```

But in this case that isn't needed:

```
gsub(pattern = "- Greek City Times", "", "Is- Greek City Times This It?")
[1] "Is This It?"
```

If you give us a way to replicate your issue I will edit further.

**EDIT:**

Given you just want to remove those string entries, how about:

```
TitleTable <- c("– Greek City Times", "- Greek City Times", "Not Greek City", "Also Not Greek City")

TitleTable[-grep("Greek City Times", TitleTable)]
[1] "Not Greek City"     
[2] "Also Not Greek City"
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. but for some reasons nothing worked for me. my scenario is..... I have a table named "master.DF.new$Title", within which I wanna get rid of all the data entry with "– Greek City Times"

Comment: See the edits above and let me know if that works for you

Comment: can u please explain what is happening in those 2 lines?

Comment: I created a character vector that is supposed to be similar to your master.DF.new$Title, given I know nothing about it. I then use grep to find the pattern of "Greek City Times" ignoring the "-" because I assume that there are no other values like "+ Greek City Times" that you want to keep. grep returns to me the row numbers where the pattern is found and I use the minus sign within the subset x[-y] to remove all rows (y) from vector (x)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)

master.DF.new$Title<-stri_replace_all(master.DF.new$Title,""– Greek City Times" ,fixed = "" )
```